# How to handle backspace while reading from STDIN in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, stdin

I'm trying to read user input with this coffee code:

```
_readEmail = (program, opts, c, u, cb) ->
    program.prompt 'email: ', /^.+@.+\..+$/, (email) =>
        u.email = email
        cb()
```

However, backspace is not handled correctly. Its just read as another character, and not deleting the characters. 
Is there a simple way to handle this?

Comment: What does program.prompt do ? How are you reading from stdin ?

Comment: I'm using commander https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the readline module:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("What do you think of node.js? ", function(answer) {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log("Thank you for your valuable feedback:", answer);

  rl.close();
});
```

See http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html or https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/joyent/node/symbols/javascript/lib/readline.js for docs and examples.

Comment: This is, however, not an answer to the original question.

Comment: This doesn't handle backspaces either, and reprompts when the backspace is pressed.